# cocos 2d and box2d: How can we play multi player game by connecting two devices through WiFi?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, wifi, box2d

How can we play multi player game by connecting two devices through WiFi?

How data transfer will happen between two devices using wifi but not in bluetooth?

Comment: How is that related to cocos2d ? what OS you are using ?

Comment: @giorashc i am developing an application using cocos2d in ios and obviously i will be using mac ....

Comment: I meant that your question was not related to cocos2d, you can also use wifi with any other graphics framework. Your question is much too general. You should look for a tutorial on these subjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using  ad-hoc networking features of GKSession. The app both advertises itself on the local network and automatically connects to available peers, establishing a peer-to-peer network.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Apple's example how to transfer data between two devices via Wi-Fi: [WiTap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: using  ad-hoc networking features of GKSession. The app both advertises itself on the local network and automatically connects to available peers, establishing a peer-to-peer network.

Comment: @kowshik yes, that's what is in the readme. I've used WiTap as example to implement data transfer between two devices in the same WiFi network in my app. I think that WiTap is a good starting point to do that.

Comment: Yep That was good starting point achieved data transfer between devices using witap.....thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

For the record as we are all discovering and for the sake of completeness (or continuation) of this article...IOS 7.0 dumps the whole GKSession thing and now uses the multipeerconnectivty framework.  Some say its more complicated, but give it some time and look and understand some of Apple's examples and it's really not bad at all.